# View helper - how to use controllerBinding

Tags: ember.js

I have to show the 'coach' field from IndexController transformed by AController:

```
{{!view App.AView coach | A }}
```

To get the result I've used the workaround:

```
{{! aList = [coach] }}
{{#each a in aList itemController = "A"}}
    {{view App.AView controllerBinding = "a"}} 
{{/each}}
```

The view A cannot directly render data from the coach field. The field should be decorated by AController.

I would appreciate any help or guidance:)

http://jsfiddle.net/6Evrq/513/

Comment: What is the problem here? Ur view seems to already be pulling its value from AController.

Comment: I would like to get rid of the "each" helper and the temporary variable aList.

Comment: Is this what u want? http://jsfiddle.net/6Evrq/515/

Comment: Exactly. Blessan, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to specify the controller for the view when its initialised. The code will look like

```
App.AView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'a-a',
  setup:function() {
    this.set("controller", App.AController.create({
      model:this.get("controller.aList")
    }));
  }.on('init')
});
```

[Here is a link to the working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/6Evrq/515/)